# Running shell script as system service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, systemd

I'm running shell script as system service but then it isn't working like it works running normally

```
input="/home/sipl/inf"
while read -r line
do
  sudo iptables -t nat -i $line -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000
done < "$input"
```

```
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH Diskutilization[7384]: Bad argument `PREROUTING'
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH Diskutilization[7384]: Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH sudo[7383]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH sudo[7385]:     root : PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -i -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 1:65535 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH sudo[7385]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH Diskutilization[7386]: Bad argument `PREROUTING'
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH Diskutilization[7386]: Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
Sep 06 17:48:44 sipl-NUC7PJYH sudo[7385]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Where is your .service file?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas in /etc/systemd/system/test.service

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your log:

```
COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -i -A PREROUTING ...
```

you do not have in variable `line` name of the interface. Correct this and you will have success.
This should be something like:

```
COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -i eth0 -A PREROUTING ...
```

Comment: I am picking the interface name from a file

Comment: @roXx You're reading lines (well, [sort of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618)). There's probably an *empty* line. Due to [lack of quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) `$line` in your code expands to zero words.